# Java: How to test if individual characters are even or odd?

Tags: java

In Java, how do I test if a character is an even or odd digit?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddOrEven{
   public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          int number, digit1, digit2, digit3;

          System.out.print( "Enter three-digit number: " );// prompt
          number = input.nextInt(); // read number 
          // determine the 3 digits
          digit1 = number / 100;
          digit2 = number % 100 / 10;
          digit3 = number % 100 % 10;

          if (digit1 % 2 == 0 && digit2 % 2 == 0 && digit3 % 2 == 0);
              System.out.println( "This number contains all even digits.");

          if (digit1 % 2 != 0 && digit2 % 2 == 0 && digit3 % 2 == 0);
              System.out.println("This number contains both odd and even digits.");

          if (digit1 % 2 != 0 && digit2 % 2 != 0 && digit3 % 2 == 0 );
            System.out.println("This number contains both odd and even digits.");   

          if (digit1 % 2 == 0  && digit2 % 2 != 0 && digit3 % 2 == 0 );
            System.out.println("This number contains both odd and even digits."); 

          if (digit1 % 2 == 0  && digit2 % 2 != 0 && digit3 % 2 != 0);
            System.out.println("This number contains both odd and even digits."); 

          if (digit1 % 2 != 0 && digit2 % 2 != 0 && digit3 % 2 != 0);
            System.out.println("This number contains all odd digits.");
   }
}
```

Comment: First you have to get each digit. Do you know how to do that? Have you looked at the `String` methods?

Comment: For a good SO question, you need to show what you've tried, and how it's failing.

Comment: I just started learning java this week so I'm looking all over for help - our texts don't have any examples like this.

Answer (score 4):

If the number you are working with is an `int` (or a similar primitive type like `long`) then you can do something like this

```
int num = // something
while (num != 0) {
    int digit = num % 10;
    System.out.println(digit + " is " + (digit % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"));
    num /= 10;
}
```

This will iterate over the digits from right to left.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int num = 28172;
    String temp = Integer.toString(num);
    int[] numArray = new int[temp.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        numArray[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    for (int i : numArray) {
        System.out.println("Num " + i + " is " + ((i % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd"));
    }

}
```

Gives me the output:

```
Num 2 is even
Num 8 is even
Num 1 is odd
Num 7 is odd
Num 2 is even
```

First, convert the `int` to a `String`. Then, since `Strings` are `Character` `arrays`, you can loop through each `character` in the `array` and turn it into an `Integer` by subtracting the ascii `Character` 0. Then, you can loop through each `Integer` in this array, and use the `mod` operator (`%`) which will give you the remainder of a division. `num%2==0` will return `true` if the number is even, otherwise `false`.